# Output specific variables in canvas JSON in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, json, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have made a Fabricjs canvas where the user can move around images and so on... I use `JSON.stringify(canvas)` to get all the data in text. The problem is that i get ALL the data when i just want certain ones like `scaleX`, `ScaleY`,`Angle` ect. How can i do this?

***HTml***

```
<div id="CanvasContainer">
    <canvas id="Canvas" width="270" height="519"></canvas>
</div>
```

***Javascript***

```
function exportData(){
    JSON.stringify(canvas);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON without additional properties

```
var json = canvas.toJSON();
```

JSON with additional properties included

```
var json = canvas.toJSON(['lockMovementX', 'lockMovementY', 'lockRotation', 'lockScalingX', 'lockScalingY', 'lockUniScaling']);
```

JSON without default values

```
canvas.includeDefaultValues = false;
var json = canvas.toJSON();
```

Comment: This saved the day but I wonder what is considered "additional properties"?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a replacer function as a second argument to the `JSON.stringify` function.

```
var wantedKeys = ['scaleX', 'scaleY', 'angle'];

JSON.stringify({ scaleX: 0, scaleY: 1, angle: 3, notThisOne: 4}, function (key, value) {
    if (!key || wantedKeys.indexOf(key) !== -1) return value;
}); //{"scaleX":0,"scaleY":1,"angle":3}
```

The replacer can also simply be an array of keys to keep:

```
JSON.stringify({ scaleX: 0, scaleY: 1, angle: 3, notThisOne: 4}, wantedKeys);
```